# Import FastClick

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, fastclick.js

I'm using [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) with [FastClick.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fastclick/fastclick.d.ts). TSC is using `module: "commonjs"` and I'm bundling with Webpack. I can't figure out how to reference FastClick.

How can I import FastClick into TypeScript? If I do this:

```
import {FastClick} from 'fastclick'
FastClick.attach(document.body);
```

I get no TSC compile errors, but the transpiled code looks like this:

```
var fastclick_1 = require('fastclick');
fastclick_1.FastClick.attach(document.body)
```

Which doesn't work. `fastclick_1` appears to be the `FastClick` function itself.

If I do this:

```
import * as FastClick from 'fastclick'
FastClick.attach(document.body)
```

I get a compile error `Error:(6, 49) TS2339: Property 'attach' does not exist on type 'typeof fastclick'`, but the emitted JS works:

```
var FastClick = require('fastclick');
FastClick.attach(document.body);
```

So how can I get TSC and the emitted JS to both work? Is the `FastClick.d.ts` wrong? Am I importing the module wrong?

Answer (score 4):

@basarat never merged his pull request. Calling `attach` via bracket notation will prevent the TSC error and emit the proper JS.

```
import * as FastClick from 'fastclick';
FastClick['attach'](document.body);
```

It's not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the FastClick.d.ts wrong

Yes. Definitely Typed is best effort (like most documentation efforts disconnected from source) and wrong in this case.

Comment: Ok. What's wrong with it? How can it be made right?

Comment: Brilliant, that fixed it! Can you explain the fix?

Comment: the declaration was exporting the wrong thing. I've exported the right thing